# Finding almost Duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way to retrieve data which could be "more or less" the same record duplicated.

Sample data:

```
+----+----------+------+--------------------------+
| ID |   Date   | Item |        Descripion        |
+----+----------+------+--------------------------+
| 11 | 1/1/2018 | CPU  | CPU needs replacement    |
| 11 | 1/2/2018 | CPU  | CPU requires replacement |
| 12 | 1/1/2018 | CPU  | CPU needs replacement    |
+----+----------+------+--------------------------+
```

First two records are duplicate while the last one is not.

**Logic**

If it is the same ID and the time span is less than or equal to 2 days, holding the same item.

**Output**

A dataset sorted by ID which contains almost duplicate data.

Comment: what is expected output? row 1 and 2?

Comment: What is `1/2/2018`? Second of January (USA), or first of February (rest of the civilised world)? Why do you say "almost duplicate" when you are checking for an exact match on ID? What is "almost" about it?

Comment: To do this you need the following information: Which records do you want to compare. How do you calculate the difference between fields in the record. If you have both you can join, compare and select the records where the compare value is high enough.

Comment: 1/2/2018 second of January.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use Oracle reserved keyword as column name, like `DATE` as you have to put it in double quote all the time.

Now, I believe you need something like below but hard to tell without your expected output. Also you should try giving a better resultset. In this case, if you have same `ID` for multiple days and if in any or those days there is a difference of less than 2 days, you will get all the rows.

To get only the records where the difference is <=2 days, use

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cbdc/5)**

```
SELECT ID,"DATE",ITEM,DESCRIPTION 
 FROM   
    (SELECT T.*, 
        LEAD(TRUNC("DATE"), 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "DATE") 
        - 
        TRUNC("DATE") 
    AS DIF1,

        TRUNC("DATE")
        -
        LAG(TRUNC("DATE"), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "DATE") 
    AS DIF2
    FROM   FOCUS_SAMPLE T                   
    ) T1 
  WHERE  T1.DIF1 <= 2 OR T1.DIF2 <=2
```

To get all records in case there is even 1 match use

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b14eea/15)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   FOCUS_SAMPLE 
WHERE  ID IN (SELECT ID 
              FROM   (SELECT T.*, 
                             LEAD(TRUNC("DATE"), 1) 
                               OVER ( 
                                 PARTITION BY ID 
                                 ORDER BY "DATE") - TRUNC("DATE") AS DIF 
                      FROM   FOCUS_SAMPLE T) T1 
              WHERE  T1.DIF <= 2)
```

Comment: Interested to Get all the records which have all the criteria met. ID is the same and date <=2 days and item is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,
here we are using rowid to delete duplicate row.

```
create table temp as
select 11 id,sysdate mdate,'CPU' item,' CPU needs replacement' description from dual union all
select 11 id,sysdate-2 mdate,'CPU' item,'  CPU requires replacement' description from dual union all
select 12 id,sysdate mdate,'CPU' item,' CPU needs replacement' description from dual ;
```

For selection:

```
select * from temp where id in (
select  id from temp a where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from temp b where a.id=b.id and b.mdate  between a.mdate-2 and a.mdate  )
) order by id ;
```

For deletion:

```
delete * from temp a where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from temp b where a.id=b.id and b.mdate  between a.mdate-2 and a.mdate  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be "duplicate" free, you can use `NOT EXISTS` to filter rows where an earlier record within the limit of two days exists.

```
SELECT *
       FROM "ELBAT" "T1"
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM "ELBAT" "T2"
                                WHERE "T2"."ID" = "T1"."ID"
                                      AND "T2"."ITEM" = "T1"."ITEM"
                                      AND "T2"."ROWID" <> "T1"."ROWID"
                                      AND "T1"."DATE" - "T2"."DATE" >= 0
                                      AND "T1"."DATE" - "T2"."DATE" <= 2);
```

If you want to only have "duplicates", you can use `EXISTS` to only keep rows, where another record in plus/minus two days exists.

```
SELECT *
       FROM "ELBAT" "T1"
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM "ELBAT" "T2"
                            WHERE "T2"."ID" = "T1"."ID"
                                  AND "T2"."ITEM" = "T1"."ITEM"
                                  AND "T2"."ROWID" <> "T1"."ROWID"
                                  AND ABS("T1"."DATE" - "T2"."DATE") <= 2);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=df9d015af0dfcf5e8d1f55947879c60d)

Comment: Running your script in production still brings unique records and records which are not close to duplicate. Your Query missed addressing that not only should ID be equal, also the ITEM should be the same.

Comment: @szakwani: I added the additional condition for the item. Doesn't make a change in general though.

Comment: I used your query, it has two major issues. It brings back records which have only 1 ID and secondly The Item is not Equal

Comment: I don't understand what that should mean. And before that becomes a useless array of comments consider to post a new question and this time include a comprehensive description and a comprehensive set of sample data and expected results to illustrate from the beginning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687892/retrieve-near-perfect-match-in-oracle-sql